# How to append another excel data into sqlite3 database in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I need to import multiple excel file data into an SQLite database, these excel files generated weekly basis having the same naming convention and data structure.

in my code 1st file data imported successfully, when I am trying to import the 2nd file it is giving me an error.

[image]

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
filename="cps"
con=sqlite3.connect(filename+".db")
wb = pd.read_excel('CPS\cps29.xlsx',sheet_name = None)
for sheet in wb:

    wb[sheet].to_sql(sheet,con,index=False)
    con.commit()
    con.close()
```

I need to append data into my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`if_exists='append'`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) to insert new rows if the table already exists (and if the table does not exist, it will be created):

```
for sheet in wb:
    wb[sheet].to_sql(sheet, con, index=False, if_exists='append')
    con.commit()
con.close()
```

Also note that `con.close()` should not be called inside the `for-loop`. Call it once after the for-loop, after all the data has been committed.